# É possível usar timestamp sem ter que converter para String no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Tenho uma query que um de seus filtros é uma data, é possível filtrar no Oracle com algo do tipo abaixo?

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campoData = '2014-02-10 15:56:00.000'
```

Ou temos sempre que converter para String como abaixo?

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campoData = TO_DATE('10/02/2014 15:56:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss')
```

Estou usando Oracle 10g.

Comment: Philippe, você está se referindo a queries executadas dentro de um software *client* como SQL Developer ou Toad? Ou está pensando em alguma linguagem de programação?

Comment: *Client* mesmo, no Java eu utilizo java.sql.Timestamp e ele se vira pra mim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo uma [documentação do Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) existem os literais de data.

Montei uma query bem simples para exemplificar:

```sql
SELECT DATE '1998-12-25', TIMESTAMP '1984-03-01 09:26:50.124' FROM DUAL;
```

Obtive a seguinte saída no SQL Developer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segundo a própria documentação você pode fazer algo como:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE datecol = DATE '2002-10-03';
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu queria. Obrigado!